# Jerk in transition from fullscreen to nonfullscreen android

Tags: android, android-theme

I am having a camera activity which is not having action bar, instead have implemented toolbar for side panel. And applied theme `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`. This screen is also not having status bar.
When i try to open a new activity from side panel, which has status bar and theme as `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, the transition is not smooth causes jerk.
Can anyone suggest me what needs to be changed

Comment: Specify what kind of jerk, post a gif or video if you can